# What may cause a limit on SG_IO ioctl maximum sector count of a transfer?

Tags: limit, transfer, ioctl, ata

I need to pass a direct ATA request to a hard drive (0x25, `READ DMA EXT`), to disobey max sector count (long story), and to bypass all possible OS caches, buffers, reorderings et al.

`HDIO_DRIVE_TASKFILE` IOCTL is no longer available due to `libata`.

I accomplished the goal with a `SG_IO` IOCTL with ATA pass-through (`SG_ATA_16`). Works perfectly except one problem: I can read a maximum of 8192 sectors in one command. I *need* to read a full of 32767 sectors.

- **max_hw_sectors_kb** is 32767, so the drive *supports* this much transfer
- **max_sectors_kb** was low, yet I brought it up to 32767 sectors, to no avail
- **scheduler** is set to *noop*, no change.
- Tried gather buffer (`iovec_count>0`, properly set `iovecs` to consecutive buffer slices), no change.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04/16.10/17.04 with standard kernels, SATA drive connected to standard AHCI interface on Intel chipset.

No matter what I do, starting with 8193 sectors, IOCTL bails out with "*Invalid argument*" error.

Where to look? What else can cause a 4MB data transfer cap?